# Rename files depending on age

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script

```
for d in $(find /home/users/*/personal/*/docs/MY -type d); do
    find $d -maxdepth 1 -type f -amin -10
done
```

It will list all files in MY directory created in period of 10 minutes in Linux server. I am looking for a way how to do that all these searched files matching criterias will be renamed by adding prefix old_. I mean if script finds files `aaaa` and `bbbb`, then renames them to `old_aaa` and `old_bbbb`.

Could someone help me?

Comment: This does not reference the time files were created, but merely the last time the files were accessed.  It is not at all trivial to determine the time a file was created, and indeed involves major changes to the file system.

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 1):

Let `find` find all the files for you:

```
find /home/users/*/personal/*/docs/MY -type f -amin +10 -print0 |  
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' path; do
    dir=$(dirname "$path")
    name=$(basename "$path")
    if [[ $name != old_* ]]; then
        echo mv "$path" "$dir/old_$name"
    fi
done
```

Remove the "echo" when you're satisfied it's working for you.

Comment: Thank you, script executes without errors, but it's not able to change files :( I don't see annoucements from "echo" either...

Comment: Do you see *any* output? Did you cut-and-paste or retype (with typos?) that code?

Comment: No, I don't. But after changing parameter to -amin -10. It works! Thank you. This is nice script!

Comment: I'm new user here and I see that I'm not allowed to vote because I need reputation 15 :( Nevertheless thank you one more time!

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `-exec`:

```
find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f -amin -10 -exec mv "{}" "old_{}" \;
```

Comments:

1. Use quotes to make sure spaces don't matter. For the loop above, you should use

   ```
   find "/home/users/"*"/personal/"*"/docs/MY" -type d
   ```

   This isn't strictly necessary but it's good to turn this into a habit so you don't forget it *when* it matters.

   Also note that the `*` must be *outside* the quotes.
2. The quotes around `{}` protect the special characters so the `find` command sees them (otherwise, the shell would try to interpret them). For the same reason, there is a `\` before the `;`

**[EDIT]** You may want to add a `\! -name "old_*"` to that which means "don't rename files that already start with `_old`" to the find.

Comment: Thanks for explanations, but something is wrong. Script is trying to rename all path but not just a file. I get error :   mv: cannot move `/home/users/*/personal/*/docs/MY/testfile.txt' to `old_/home/users/*/personal/*/docs/MY/testfile.txt': No such file or directory ....Any ideas how it could be corrected?

Comment: Did you notice that you must keep the `*` outside of the quotes?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a quotes. I'm not getting error right now, but new files are not renamed after upload.

Comment: Try `-amin +10` (i.e. "older than 10 minutes")

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want old_old_old_old_... files you should try the following:

```
find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f -amin -10  -exec grep -q -v "old_" {} \; -exec mv "{}" "old_{}" \;
```

PS: I woul'd have commented the previous post but I am not allowed to.

Comment: I tried your command also. But error the same as I got with Aaron improvement mv: cannot move /home/users/*/personal/*/docs/MY/testfile.txt' to old_/home/users/*/personal/*/docs/MY/testfile.txt': No such file or directory It's trying to rename all path... How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Do like follows:

```
for d in $(find /home/users/*/personal/*/docs/MY -type d); do
    find $d -maxdepth 1 -type f -amin -10 | { read bn; basename "$bn"; } | rename "s/()/old_\$1/"
done
```

Also take in mind that `-amin -10` refers to files being accesed in the last 10 minutes, that includes files created in last 10 minutes but could contain other files as well.

**Update**:
An alternative way, which is probably faster than above one, because it uses `mv` command to rename and so it doesn't involve with regex, is the following:

```
for d in $(find /home/users/*/personal/*/docs/MY -type d); do
    find $d -maxdepth 1 -type f -amin -10 | { read bn; basename "$bn"; } | { read fn; mv "$fn" "old_$fn"; }
done
```

**Update 2**:
I've updated my two commands above to fix the errors that OP noted in comments.

Comment: Entering in shell first command written of yours I got error:  for d in $(find /home/users/*/personal/*/docs/MY -type d); do find $d -maxdepth 1 -type f -amin -10 | rename "s/()/old_\$1/" ; done
call: rename from to files...

Comment: And executing command after update the error the same as in examples above. Why all scripts trying to change "path" and not founded files. Error:  mv: cannot move /home/users/*/personal/*/docs/MY/testfile.txt' to old_/home/users/*/personal/*/docs/MY/testfile.txt'

Comment: Use `xargs` instead of `read` and `-print0` to avoid problems with strange characters

Comment: I've updated my answer again to fix the issue you're reporting, try it and comment if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for corrections, but it looks that the different error comes out. mv: cannot stat `': No such file or directory